# Assign variables from nested JSON string using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Wondering if anyone can help me figure out away to assign the body context to my `description String variable.`

Here is my JSON string

{"requirement":{"description":{"body":"This is a text"}}}

```
public class Requirement implements Serializable {

    private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

I know I can use `@JsonProperty("description")` but my description is nested with different context. In this case I only care about the body.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question correctly. You can simply parse you JSON and extract whatever you want from it, but seems it is not what you are looking for?

Comment: You should have a RequirementModel, a DescriptionModel and a BodyModel, and in DescriptionModel there is a `private BodyModel body;` and then extract the string from the `BodyModel` object.

Comment: I just edited my question. I wrote the json incorrectly

Comment: @cokeby190 Thats what I have done. I have a model/POJO for Requirements, description, etc. Im just wondering instead of creating a POJO for Description just assign the body to a description string in requirement POJO

Comment: Ah I see, this part I am not too familiar with sorry!

Comment: But from what I understand if you were to use Jackson it would be the model/POJO format, unless you were to parse the json manually yourself.

Comment: Than could I make a description variable in requirements so it can build {"requirement": {"description": "<p>This is the description</p>"}} when going from POJO to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have the class with same structure as the json, you'll have to first unpack the description object and extract body:

```
public class Requirement {
private String body;

@JsonProperty("description")
private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> description) {
    this.body = (String)description.get("body");
}
```

}

Comment: What is `(String)brand.get("body")`? Im getting an error on `brand`

Comment: Edited it, check.

Comment: Maybe not but sometimes its required to map to different variables

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure actually looks like this

```
class Requirement{
  private Description description;
}
class Description{
  private String body;
}
```

just add proper `@JsonProperty` and you will be fine.

In general, every json Object is a separate class (unless you map to plan maps)

Comment: Yes I know but I want to avoid this by just assigning the body of description to a variable in requirement POJO.

Comment: This is how Jackson work. Your requirement is some sort of rare modeling issue that. Since this is exact reflection of your data model - change the model.